# z/OS Syncsort: omit duplicates without sort

Tags: duplicates, syncsort

It can’t be figured out with the manual how to manage this problem with syncsort (we found solutions with dfsort which didn’t help).
Due to a program error (which can’t be fixed in time, you know: programmer, test, quality check, deployment...) we got duplicate records in a file (FB/LRECL 250) where then

- a header line exists
- subsequent duplicate data lines which have to be omitted but the one unique
- data lines must not be sorted (due to obligate logical relations of some records)
- the trailer includes the data line count.

The file can not manually be edited because of its size (>2 mio records).

example infile:

```
HEADER xxxx
cccc
bbbb 123
bbbb 123
bbbb 123
dddd
aaaa 123
aaaa 123
aaaa
TRAILER COUNT: 8
```

Expected outfile:

```
HEADER xxxx
cccc
bbbb 123         
dddd
aaaa 123
aaaa
TRAILER COUNT: 5
```

So the outfile is not sorted at all, the omitted records

```
bbbb 123         (omitted)
bbbb 123         (omitted)
aaaa 123         (omitted)
```

are not needed at all and may go straight into Nirvana.

(I would even be happy with a solution omitting header/trailer as I could easily concatenate manually generated lines in the subsequent job.)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve your expected result using two SYNCSORT steps.

**Step 1:**

```
INREC FIELDS=(1:SEQNUM,4,ZD,5:1,8)
SORT FIELDS=(5,8,CH,A),SKIPREC=1  
SUM FIELDS=NONE
```

Using **INREC**, I've appended Sequence number in the first 4 bytes followed by the actual data record. Then, I've sorted the file with first 8 bytes as the key. Header record is being skipped using **SKIPREC**.

**Step 2:**

```
SORT FIELDS=(1,4,CH,A)                                              
OUTFIL FNAMES=SORTOF01,REMOVECC,                                    
OUTREC=(1:5,8,80:X),TRAILER1=('TRAILER COUNT:',COUNT=(M11,LENGTH=8))
```

In Step 2, output file from STEP 1 is being read as input. As you expect the data lines to be not sorted, I've sorted the input with Sequence number as the key. Using **OUTREC**, I'm restraining from writing the Sequence number in the final output file. I've used **TRAILER1** to print the count of records at the last.

Hope this helps. Please let me know if you've an alternative which works more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

See my below sort card. It is built for your sample data shown above.

```
//SORTOUT DD SYSOUT=*                                                 
//SYSIN DD *                                                          
 OPTION COPY                                                          
 INREC FIELDS=(1,50,SEQNUM,7,ZD,RESTART=(1,8))                        
 OUTFIL REMOVECC,OMIT=(51,7,ZD,GT,01,|,1,7,CH,EQ,C'TRAILER'),         
        OUTREC=(1,50),TRAILER1=(C'TRAILER COUNT:',COUNT-1=(M11,LENGTH=8))
/*
```